# REST API - special characters in request parameter

Tags: rest, post

I want to run a post request to insert an url (like https://www.google.com/) in a specific table.

I wanted something like http://localhost:3000/addUrl/https://www.google.com/, where the url is a parameter. However, this throws an error as it contains special characters ('/').

How can I deal with these special characters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) when you need to put a reserved character somewhere it isn't normally allowed.

The complete rules for describing how to build a URI are described by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

Many languages include libraries for manipulating URI data structures, so you probably don't need to create your own.